# How to style elements to overlap per container width (to look like tabs)?

Tags: css, flexbox, tabs, css-grid, margin

I have a list of items that are styled to display in a row, with each one overlapping the other slightly, to look like tabs. Using only CSS (no JS), I would like the overlap to change responsively to the window width, such that when the window decreases in width, the overlap of each list item becomes greater. How can this be accomplished?

Below is simplified example code. I’m accomplishing the overlap via negative `margin`, but if there’s a better way, I’m open to it. How can I write a `calc()` function (or use some other method) to do this? Or should I be using `flexbox` or `grid-template-columns` somehow instead?

```css
li {
  background-color  : orange;
  border            : 5px dashed red;
  box-sizing        : border-box;
  display           : inline-block;
  font-size         : 20px;
  height            : 100%;
  line-height       : 30px;
  opacity           : 0.75;
  position          : relative;
  width             : 100px;
  margin            : 0;
  margin-right      : -10px;
  /* 
-15px;      This would make a greater overlap, but I want it to be responsive to the container width.
calc(100%); How can something like that be calculated?
  */
  }
ul {
  background  : brown;
  box-sizing  : border-box;
  font-size   : 0;
  height      : 40px;
  margin      : 0;
  overflow    : hidden;
  padding     : 0;
  position    : relative;
  text-align  : center;
  white-space : nowrap;
  width       : 100%;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
  <li>item 8</li>
</ul>
```

Here is a Codepen for your sandbox editing if helpful: https://codepen.io/jtheletter/pen/vYveLZJ

Comment: With such colors, seeing the overlap is not easy...

Comment: @MisterJojo, the colors don’t matter at all. Please change them as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that, for your calculation?

```css
ul > li {
  display          : inline-block;
  background-color : whitesmoke;
  border           : 1px solid black;
  border-radius    : 1em;
  width            : 4em;
  height           : 2em;
  line-height      : 2em;
  padding          : 0 .7em;
  margin           : 0 0 0 calc( 4vw - 60px ); /* same as (-60px - ( 4vw * -1 )); */
  list-style       : none;
  }
  
/* class for testing width values : */
div { height: 2em; margin: 1em ; }
div.q1 { width:  4vw;             background: lightblue; }
div.q2 { width: 60px;             background: yellow;    }
div.q3 { width: calc(60px - 4vw); background: orangered; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
</ul>

<p><br>tests of width values :</p>

<div class="q1">4vw</div>
<div class="q2">60px</div>
<div class="q3">60px&nbsp;-&nbsp;4vw</div>
```

Comment: That does not appear to change the overlap at all in response to change in window width. https://codepen.io/jtheletter/pen/yLGzeqB?editors=1100

Comment: @2540625 your observation is wrong:  the overlap changes when with the width of the window (1vh = 1%)

Comment: I altered your colors, and I now see it is increasing the overlap with reduction of window width, thank you greatly. Can you elaborate on how you came to that equation? @Mister Jojo

Comment: @2540625 simple: 1) the 1vw value increases or decreases with that of the window
2) as you want the opposite, you must therefore subtract this value from a fixed size
3) but as only a negative value allows overlapping it is necessary to reverse the signs on all values.

Comment: @2540625 yesterday I was in a bit of a hurry: I have now simplified this equation. I left the previous equation to allow you to understand the reasoning to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You where so close, the thing is you need to calculate how much you want the overlap:

Try:
**margin-right: calc(10% - 100px);**

```
ul {
  position: relative;
  background: gray;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.2);
  border: 5px dashed red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: calc(10% - 100px);
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
```